# How do I segment head and body in a top-down depth map of a cow?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, semantic-segmentation

I am using OpenCV to process images and extract the largest area from an area and remove any background information. The images are pictures of cows, used to estimate their weight. To estimate the weight correctly, I need to remove the head from the images to be processed.

Currently (image 1) I am able to extract the largest area (the cow with the head) from the picture, but want to extract only the body (image 2).

Original Code:

[image: 1]

Area to Extract:

[image: 2]

```
img = cv2.imread(subdir + '\\' + img_name + '.png')
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()

#COnvert to hue, saturation, and value
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv_img)
hsv_split = np.concatenate((h,s,v),axis=1)

# Use the hue value to convert to binary
thresh = 20
thresh, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(h, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                    
# Finding Contours
# Use a copy of the image since findContours alters the image

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_img.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
                        
#Extract the largest area
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Is there anyway to remove this portion of the image using openCV?

Comment: Threshold, then get a count of every column of non-zero pixels. The one with the minimum (other than zero count) is the neck. Crop from there. See np.count_nonzero()

Comment: Run ````convexHull()```` on the cow object, ````findContours()````  for dark objects in that area and select the biggest two. That should give the two empty spaces alongside the neck. Connect their centers of mass to crop the 'cow' object. (*So* many puns possible..., *must* resist... :D)

Comment: You could try morphological operations like erosion on your binary image. Increase the kernel size until you get 2 components, at which point the head and torso should be seperated. Then do a watershed floodfill to get the boundary between head and torso.

Comment: we'll need some actual data instead of those composite pictures. please [edit] your question and add a mask image that only shows cow, without bars. -- to expand on fwm42's answer: you'll encounter corner cases, if you only test for narrowest column. assuming this was two blobby spheres, they're also "narrow" at the ends of the spheres (snout, tail) for some vertical scanlines. you'll have to recognize that condition. perhaps simply find the beginning and end of the object, then disregard for some small distance starting from there.