# Camera pose estimation from a bird view image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to calculate the camera pose from a "warpPerspective" processed image.
I start with the original camera image, then I undistort it and finally get the bird view one:

[image]

I've already estimated the camera pose from both the original and the undistorted images using `solvePnp()` and `Rodrigues()` where I've passed the instrinsic matrix and distortion coefficients taken from the calibration process (for the undistorted case I had to use cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix instead of mtx and 0 for dist in solvePnp(), more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74566271/opencv-camera-pose-estimation-gives-different-results-between-distorted-and-undi) in comments section).

Now I have the image points(2d) and the corrisponding real world ones(3d) for the bird view image but I don't know what camera matrix I need to use as input for solvePnp in this case (I assume that the distortion coefficients must be 0 as the "undistorted" case, right?).
Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to help you with your problem, sorry. But the second cow/python/openCV question today ? What are the chances ? :D 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595357/how-do-i-segment-head-and-body-in-a-top-down-depth-map-of-a-cow#comment131674361_74595357